# Regex AND in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have these possible inputs

```
Defender el anteproyecto;
Defender los anteproyectos;
Defender;
Anteproyectos
```

I need a python regex that can match only the first 2 but not the last 2. I've tried `r"(?i)defender (anteproyectos?)?"` with no success and will only be achieved with something like the Python logic: `if "xyz" and "uvw" in "abc"`

Comment: *the first 2 but not the last*. What is the rules of matching? The first word should always be `defender`, the second `el` or `los` ?

Comment: Have a try with: `(?i)defender.+?anteproyectos?`

Comment: @Toto tanks that worked!

Comment: @Toto: wouldn't that match the first three?

Comment: @l'L'l: No because the second word (ie. `anteproyecto` or `anteproyectos`) is mandatory in the regex.

Comment: @Toto: Maybe I'm not fully awake yet, although take a look @ https://regex101.com/r/L7Qs1p/1

Comment: @l'L'l: The last two examples are not on the same line, they are independant.

Comment: @Toto: Ah, okay... the OP had showed them on the same line originally, so that's why I was confused. I guess if it were either scenario `(?i)(defender[^;]+;)` might be the way to go...

Comment: @l'L'l:You're right, but OP seems to be OK with that.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `(?i)defender (anteproyectos?)?` you're making `anteproyecto` (with or without `s`) optional, make it mandatory and don't forget the word in between:

```
(?i)defender.+?anteproyectos?
```

Answer (score 0):

If your secondary terms change at all, or your input string is single or multi-line this might work:

```
(?i)(defender[^;]+;)
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/L7Qs1p/3